# Random variable with all higher order moments zero?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is there a random variable with finite first and second moment but all higher order (non-central) moments are zero?

Comment: If there is, it's characteristic function would need to be a second-degree polynomial, i.e. of the form $\varphi(t) = a\cdot t^2 + b\cdot t + c$. This follows from $\mathbb{E}(X^k) = (-i)^k \varphi_X^{(k)}(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be your random variable on $\mathbb R$. If the (non central) 4th moment is zero, we have
$$ \mathbb E X^4 = \mathbb E |X|^4 = 0. $$
That is, $X$ must be $0$ almost surely. Quite boring :)

Comment: Thanks. I must be on crack :P

Comment: @user251257: why $ \mathbb E X^4 = \mathbb E |X|^4 $ ?

Comment: @Mathmath because $X$ is assumed real valued in the answer.